# Es fährt auch immer "das neuest" Auto oder "das neueste" Auto?

Tags: grammar, adjective, adjective-ending

> Das italienisch Restaurant oder italienische Restaurant?
>
> Das neu Fitnessstudio oder das neue Fitnessstudio?

Vielen Dank im Voraus!

Comment: https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Flexion:neu

Comment: I corrected your question: Adjectives before a noun are written in small letters in German! And voraus is capitalized in "im Voraus" (http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/im_Voraus)

Answer (score 3):

Correct is:

> Das italienische Restaurant.
>
> Das neue Fitnessstudio.
>
> Das neueste Auto.

The reason is that adjectives belonging to a noun with a definite article in nominative singular neuter (das Auto, das Restaurant, das Fitnessstudio) always get declined by appending an "e". See [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_adjectives) for further explanations.

Comment: You could improve your answer by explaining *why* this is correct.